# changed theme -> Logged out -> No log in field shown :(

Tags: users

I cant find the log-in or registration fields on my wellcome page after i changed my theme and loged out myself.

How can i make the log in field visible again?

thank you for help.

Comment: try go to example.com/?q=user

Comment: Did you check that any region is assigned to user login block?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the following path:
http://www.yoursite.com/?q=user/login